# apache kafka multiple producer vs single producer performance

Tags: apache-kafka

I have kafka cluster with 12 brokers in a single machine and one zookeeper in same machine
I use kafka-python to produce messages

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='localhost:9092'  , acks=0 , linger_ms=10000 , batch_size=2000000 , buffer_memory=1003554432)

for i in range(50000):

    #50 Bytes message
    msg= 'FDASFAFAFAFAFADDFASFADFAFDASFAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF'

    #my_topic has 12 partitions , kafka cluster has 12 brokers in single machine
    producer.send('my_topic', msg)
```

when I run my python code, I achieve throughput 20,000 (messages per second)
but, when I run multiple same python code simultaneously, I achieve same throughput (20,000 messges per second)

how can I achieve better throughput when I run single producer ??

I test many batch.size and linger.ms values but I can not achieve better performance

Comment: Might want to look at some other Kafka python benchmarks to see how you compare. Also running 12 brokers and a zookeeper on the same machine is not a great configuration for performance. Check that your messages are actually going to all 12 partitions and not bottlenecked on one at a time. http://activisiongamescience.github.io/2016/06/15/Kafka-Client-Benchmarking/

Comment: @HansJespersen confluent works better, i 50 ,000 per second with conluent kafka, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Performance of Kafka producer depends on the Kafka cluster, in your code you are continuously trying to publish the messages to Kafka. I also had the same experience while doing the performance testing through my tool. If the capacity of the Kafka cluster is low, then throughput will not increase by parallel producers.
If Kafka cluster has more capacity then more number of producers will lead to higher number of messages being produced.

Setup the proper Kafka cluster(with min 3 brokers in 3 diff machines 16 GB ram,some good cpu ) with separate zookeeper cluster, have the topic properly portioned(more partitions) and replicated across Kafka brokers. Now if you test ur producer code, it works as expected.

Comment: actually I have some limitation for using different physical servers. for now,I have only one good server and I have to run virtual machine in it, the point is that the bottleneck is not Kafka cluster, the Kafka-produer-perf-test.sh achieve 100.000 message/per second and I realize that the producer I used does not work perfect, so I change my library( use Confluent Kafka python) I achieve better performance and I am happy now : ))